# Free PDF reader for Android phone that has a "Go To page" function

Tags: pdf

Is there a free PDF reader for the Android phone that has a "Go To page" function?

When I try to read a 600+ page document on my smartphone I find it tedious to scroll to the page I'm interested in. It takes a lot of time and is not precise. It would be much easier if possible to jump directly to the page I want (I know which page I want to see because there is a "Table of Contents" in the document - such a fresh and wonderful invention).

I tried Adobe Reader X, and my phone's default PDF reader application, but they don't seem to have an option to jump directly to a page, or at least this is not a documented feature and I didn't find how to do.

Is there an alternate (preferably free) PDF reader for Android?

Comment: Can you use the search function in Adobe Reader to search for the page number?

Comment: @Al Everett : that's a nice idea, however with my 600+ page document searches take so much time that it is practically impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VuDroid. [market](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.vudroid&feature=search_result) It has "Go to page", but can't search.

Comment: I tried vuDroid, you are right, it has this useful function. I also found that even if there is no such function in Adobe Reader X, you can quickly scroll the pages if you tap the bottom of the page (I guess the developers thought this feature didn't require documentation.)

Comment: When I installed this on my Android Samsung Galaxy 4 every time I try to open the application it crashes and just says "VuDroid" has stopped.

Answer (score 2):

You can goto page in 'fit to screen' or 'continous scroll' mode (but not 'reflow text') by touching at the bottom of the screen and it'll make a scroll bar turn up. As you drag your finger left and right you'll see the page number and total number of pages at the top left of the screen.

Edit in 2015: Slightly different now: touch at the bottom, then you'll see a page number on the right edge of the screen, which you can drag up and down.

Comment: This does not work with the default PDF Viewer that comes with Android Samsung Galaxy 4

Answer (score 2):

[Adobe Acrobat Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=en) has the function, on the right you have a little arrow with the page number, tap on it and you'll be able to enter the page number

Comment: Confirmed this works after downloading and installing on my Samsung Galaxy 4 Android device

Comment: OP is right, it doesn't seem to have the option but it is there: https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/rm/ios/acrobatios_en/nav.html#jump

Answer (score 1):

The free [PDF Annotation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cx.pdf.android.pdfview&hl=nl) app has a goto function (as well as a search function). I use it myself to read PDF and make notes while reading.

Comment: I downloaded this application but could not find any goto function.

Comment: @Kmeixner it's in the menu after you opened a document, at least that's the case on my old phone (SGS2)

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. On the lower left corner of the page you are on there is the page number. If you do not see it touch this place and the page number will appear. For example if you are on page 54 in a file 700 pages long you will see 54/700. You touch the number 54 and a request "Go to page" will appear with a supporting touch keyboard. You print the page number and OK.

Comment: This does not work with the default PDF Viewer that comes with Android Samsung Galaxy 4

Answer (score 1):

There's this service called cameyo. Basically it lets you run Windows programs through your browser or from their app. They have a wide variety of apps set up and you should find a good pdf reader there.

Answer (score 0):

Use WPS office its large and has lots of stuff you may not want. But the viewer is really good and works with TOC commands and table of content functions. Hope this helps.